# Calculating a^b, where b is a negative exponent in c#

Tags: c#, exponent

For example I am trying to calculate 9704<sup>−36</sup> in C#.
How should i go about doing this?
I am using Visual C# 2010 Express

Comment: How about `Math.Pow(9704,-36)` ?

Comment: [First thing to do](http://www.google.co.in/search?gcx=w&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=c%23+exponent)

Comment: @Nook Don't change the question. If you asked the wrong question that's your problem not ours. Now we are getting downvotes and look like idiots. If you want to ask the right question then ask it as a new question.

Comment: @nook thank you for heeding my advice and asking a [new question for your modular arithmetic question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7483706/c-modinverse-function).

Comment: @Justin OP mentioned `exponent` in the title.

Comment: @Knvn Ah - The edit I saw didn't mention exponents - its been changed since then.

Answer (score 5):

Use `Math.Pow(9704, -36)`.  C# does not have a dedicated exponentiation operator and [`Math.Pow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.pow.aspx) fills the gap.

Comment: It seems that you don't know what is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse

Comment: @grep It seems that you didn't notice that the question changed. Original question about negative exponents has been restored.

Comment: @grep you should post your deleted answer at the [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7483706/c-modinverse-function)

Answer (score 1):

Exactly the same way you do it for a positive exponent:

```
Math.Pow(9704,-36)
```

There is no power operator in C# (`^` is exclusive or, not power), so you need to use the [Math.Pow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.pow.aspx) function.